# How to create an alluvial plot in ggplot2 with ggalluvial package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I'm trying to create an alluvial plot in `ggplot2` with the `ggalluvial` package. Here are the two helpful websites I've been using to create the plot: [site 1](https://r-charts.com/flow/ggalluvial/) and [site 2](https://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/).

My goal is to use the same code found on site 1 but apply it to my own df, as shown below. However, everytime I try to do that I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(first_row, curve_data): arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 12

This is my df:

```
t1 <- c("college", "college", "college", "university", "university")
t2 <- c("law", "law", "business", "business", "business")
t3 <- c("public", "private", "private", "private", "public")
t4 <- c(2,4,6,8,10)

df <- data.frame(cbind(t1,t2,t3,t4))
names(df) <- c("Undergrad", "Grad_School", "Sector", "Freq")
```

This is the original code, as copied from site 1:

```
library(ggalluvial)
vaccinations
ggplot(data = vaccinations,
       aes(axis1 = survey,
           axis2 = response,
           axis3 = survey,
           y = freq)) +
    geom_alluvium(aes(fill = response)) +
    geom_stratum() +
    geom_text(stat = "stratum",
              aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Survey", "Response"),
                     expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
    theme_void()
```

This is my code with my df substituted in.

```
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(axis1 = Undergrad,
           axis2 = Grad_School,
           y = Freq)) +
    geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Sector)) +
    geom_stratum() +
    geom_text(stat = "stratum",
              aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Undergrad", "Grad_School"),
                     expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
    theme_void()
```

Comment: Please share the exact code you're currently trying so we can help. How did you modify the code from the example to use your data?

Comment: @DanAdams, thanks for your comment. I edited the question to show how I modified the code.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. If you clear your environment and start again, does it still give an error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. Your answer below worked perfectly. I'm still trying to understand why my code didn't work. It seems very similar to your answer.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Compare `str(df)` to `str(d)` and you'll see that yours has `chr` for `Freq` which is why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `cbind()` your vectors, you create a `matrix` which (unlike a `data.frame`) cannot contain different data types. Therefore, the `Freq` gets converted to a `character`. If you just directly create the `data.frame` without `cbind()` it works fine.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

t1 <- c("college", "college", "college", "university", "university")
t2 <- c("law", "law", "business", "business", "business")
t3 <- c("public", "private", "private", "private", "public")
t4 <- c(2,4,6,8,10)

df <- data.frame(t1,t2,t3,t4)
names(df) <- c("Undergrad", "Grad_School", "Sector", "Freq")

ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(axis1 = Undergrad,
             axis2 = Grad_School,
             y = Freq)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Sector)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Undergrad", "Grad_School"),
                   expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>